# CRM 2011: Read Permissions for Certain File Types

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

is there a way to wrap permissions around file attachments that might contain sensitive data? Currently, people are using notes to attach their files, but these are open to anyone. Is there a way to create a file type that can be selected, and then have permissions wrapped around the reading of those file types?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try to do it using plugins that handle RetrieveMultiple message of annotation entity.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by replacing the standard notes section with a silverlight component. I then made another entity that holds the metadata for each annotation around which teams can access it. Its not 100% hack proof and if you wanted to make it better then you could add a plugin as Andrii Buntenko suggested.